# Python/MySQL "Insert into" with variables

Tags: python, mysql, variables, insert-into

I have a problem with inserting new rows to the MySQL table. 
The name of the table will change, so it must be a variable and with that I have the most trouble.
How can I change name of the table "second" with variable?
Any idea?

```
add_word = ("INSERT INTO second "
               "(name, surname) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s)")
    data_word = (name1, surname1)
    cursor.execute(add_word, data_word)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
add_word = ("INSERT INTO {table} "
            "(name, surname) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s)")
atable = 'second'
data_word = (name1, surname1)
cursor.execute(add_word.format(table=atable), data_word)
```

Comment: not putting the data separately mean you will need to be very carefull to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: That's dangerous. You should be using MySQL's built in string building and escaping features.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to have the table name be data.  You will have to put it in the sql statement.  Maybe like this:

```
add_word = ("INSERT INTO {table} "
            "(name, surname) "
            "VALUES (%s, %s)")
table1 = 'second'
data_word = (name1, surname1)
cursor.execute(add_word.format(table=table1), data_word)
```