# How to inser varible in to mysql inside python

Tags: python, mysql, jira-rest-api

**Commands as .format and %s I use in every possible combination without any progress.**
It work right when I use it this way:

```
last_issue = jira.search_issues('assignee = "ahmet" order by created desc')[0]
```

But I need assignee to be a varible and if I use it this way or smthing like:

```
assignee = "ahmet"
last_issue = jira.search_issues('assignee =', assignee, 'order by created desc')[0]
```

It gives mistake like

```
response headers = {'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'X-AREQUESTID': '578x1623860x1', 'X-ASESSIONID': 'x0ubjs', 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-L0000000', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'ekaterina', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Mon, 11 Sep 2017 09:38:10 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'Server': 'nginx/1.13.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    response text =
```

How should I make a variable in appropriate way?

Comment: It doestn't work in the question above way

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757747/python-mysql-insert-into-with-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/MySQL "Insert into" with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757747/python-mysql-insert-into-with-variables)

Comment: response headers = {'X-ASESSIONID': '1652m96', 'X-AUSERNAME': 'ekaterina', 'X-AREQUESTID': '602x1624049x1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform',

Comment: What does it have to do with MySQL ???

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
 var = "assignee = '{}' order by created desc".format(assignee)
 last_issue = jira.search_issues(var)[0]
```